# What is the rank of a matrix when the difference between its rows is same?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I have this matrix:
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
1& 3 &2\\
2 &4& 3\\
3& 5& 4
\end{pmatrix}
$$
I noticed that `$R_2 - R_1 = R_3 - R_2$

How many rows are dependent in this case? and what will be the rank?

Comment: The equation you wrote demonstrates the rows are dependent.

Comment: yeah but how many of them are dependent? and how? and rank?

Comment: So you know the rank is not $3$. If you can find two rows that are not dependent, then the rank is $2$. Otherwise the rank is $1$. [The only zero rank matrix is the zero matrix.]

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

You have show that
$$
R_1-2R_2+R_3=0
$$

so the rows are linearly dependent.

but any couple of rows are linearly independent because , as you can easily see, there is not a real number $k$ such that $kR_1=R_2$ or $kR_1=R_3$ or $kR_3=R_2$ . So...

Answer (score 0):

If you solve your equation for $R_2$ you get: $R_2 = \frac{1}{2}(R_1+R_3)$ so the matrix cannot have full rank. Gaussian elimination can be used to arrive at the rank. In this case you will see one row of zero's and the matrix has 2 pivots and so the rank is 2.